# Sum column in data frame based on another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame like this:

```
Vehicle    Driver   Distance   Fuel.Consumption
    W01      Alex      22.31               0.58
    W01      Alex      93.21               2.48
    W02     Brian     122.72               3.22
    W02     Brian      22.25                0.5
......
```

I want an output like this:

```
Vehicle    Driver   Distance   Fuel.Consumption   Fuel.Efficiency
    W01     Alex      115.52               3.06             37.75
    W02    Brian      144.97               3.72             38.97      
......
```

Just sum the Distance and Fuel.Consumption of each Vehicle and compute the Fuel.Efficiency of each Vehicle.
I've tried `aggregate()`, but it's not work like what I would imagine:

```
aggregate(Distance~Vehicle, df, FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Please share your attempt with `aggregate` in your question.

Comment: @Pascal, aggregate(Distance~Vehicle, df, FUN=sum). I don't know how to do this, just try to start solving it by Distance first... I know this is kinda silly , but I do not know how to do this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always had trouble with `aggregate` syntax when trying to do more than one thing at a time. Here you want to sum two existing columns and compute a brand new column. Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Vehicle, Driver) %>%
    summarize(Distance = sum(Distance),
              Fuel.Consumption = sum(Fuel.Consumption),
              Fuel.Efficiency = Distance / Fuel.Consumption)

# Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
# Groups: Vehicle

#   Vehicle Driver Distance Fuel.Consumption Fuel.Efficiency
# 1     W01   Alex   115.52             3.06        37.75163
# 2     W02  Brian   144.97             3.72        38.97043
```

Comment: I have another question, the content of Distance column in my dataset are factor and I cannot change it into number using as.numeric( ). Could you help me with this?

Comment: @White.B.Jiang Change it into a number with `as.numeric(as.character(your_column))`.

Answer (score 2):

With `aggregate` you can summarize the Distance and Fuel Consumption like this:

```
df2 <- aggregate(. ~  Vehicle + Driver, df1, sum)
> df2
#  Vehicle Driver Distance Fuel.Consumption
#1     W01   Alex   115.52             3.06
#2     W02  Brian   144.97             3.72
```

Then you can add a column for the Fuel efficiency:

```
df2$Fuel.Efficiency <- with(df2,( Distance / Fuel.Consumption))
#> df2
#  Vehicle Driver Distance Fuel.Consumption Fuel.Efficiency
#1     W01   Alex   115.52             3.06        37.75163
#2     W02  Brian   144.97             3.72        38.97043
```

Comment: Thank you @Rhertel for your help!